# Find "LIKE" duplicates in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a MSSQL database and there's this column with IDs.
Some are {}-wrapped around the ID and some are not.

I need to find out if there are duplicate entries like:
'{abcd}' and 'abcd' in one column.

Obviously I dont know 'abcd'...

Is there a simple way of joining the same column and searching for "LIKE" duplicates? Inner Join is not working for me...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help, as would the query that you say is not working.

Comment: Are these IDs GUIDs (i.e. look something like `24ffaeb4-f17f-47bd-b03a-76f213aad457`)?  If so, you may be best off converting the column defintiion to `uniqueidentifier`.  If they're just strings though please ignore; my guess is based on the fact that `uniqueidentifier` is often used as an ID, and can be formatted with or without enclosing braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT Id
FROM TableName AS T0
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableName AS T1
    WHERE T0.Id = '{' + T1.Id + '}'
    -- Uncomment the next row if you want all duplicates (with or without brackets):
    -- OR '{' + T0.Id + '}' = T1.Id
)
```

This will return all the records where the id is wrapped by curly brackets and has duplicate id just without the brackets.

Comment: Seems like the resultset is zero, but this seems to be a both simple and correct query, thank you!

Comment: Add `'{' + T0.Id + '}' = T1.Id` to find both!

Comment: With the new "OR" it seems to need ages to complete. The query runs now over two minutes. Without the "OR" it's completed in seconds...

Comment: Then don't use it. Either get the ids with brackets or get those that don't have brackets, I don't think you really need both anyway

Comment: Separately runned, both resultsets are empty. Thanks guys!

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID VARCHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('abc'),
('{abc}'),
('def'),
('ghi'),
('{ghi}');


SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT TRIM(TRANSLATE(ID, '{}', '  ')) ID
  FROM T
) TT
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1;

-- Or you can also do

SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(ID, '{', ''), '}', '') ID
  FROM T
) TT
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1;
```

Note that **[`TRANSLATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and **[`TRIM()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** functions is available only in SQL Server 2017

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know, add a note about it, it's just another way :)